# Create JSON with data from database and JavaScript generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to create a calendar view with fullcalendar.io. For some dates, I have a specific price in my database and I retrieve it, but for some dates (without specific prices) I need to put the usual rates in the objects I need to create with JavaScript. Problem is now because I don't know how to make JSON for that.

In short: I need to have a price for every date, but for some dates I get data from database. How do I create such JSON objects in JavaScript?

I have this code:

```
var db_data = [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-25 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 55,
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-15 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 35,
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-07 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 22,
    "title": "drugi",
    "start": "2016-03-05 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 44,
    "title": "prvi",
    "start": "2016-02-04 15:18:46"
  }
];

        // declare variables
        var period_start = new Date('2016-02-02'),
            period_end = new Date('2016-03-03'),
            current_date = period_start,
            array_of_all_dates = [];

        // Create a populated array of dates
       // Create a populated array of dates
        while (current_date.getTime() <= period_end.getTime()) {
          array_of_all_dates.push(current_date);
          current_date = new Date(+current_date);
          current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 1);
        }

        // Now loop over the array of populated dates and mutate, so something like
        array_of_all_dates = array_of_all_dates.map(function (date) {
          var found_in_db = db_data.filter(function (db_data) {
            return new Date(db_data.start.replace(" ", "T")).getTime() === date.getTime(); // You need to do this comparison better!
          });
          if (found_in_db.length > 0) {
            return found_in_db[0];
          }
          var new_object = {
            title: '',
            start: date,
            price: '{{$article->price}}'
          };
          console.log(new_object);
          return new_object;

        });



        console.log('result'+array_of_all_dates);
        drawCalendar(array_of_all_dates);
```

And with this code I get data from database and dates (start) which are not excist in database I create with JavaScript.

But with this function I get this data and I can't create calendar:
[image]

I also try with this:

```
// Now loop over the array of populated dates and mutate, so something like
    array_of_all_dates = array_of_all_dates.map(function (date) {
      var found_in_db = db_data.filter(function (db_data) {
        var db_data_date = new Date(db_data.start.replace(" ", "T"));
        return db_data_date.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() &&
                        db_data_date.getMonth() === date.getMonth() &&
                db_data_date.getDay() === date.getDay();
      });
      if (found_in_db.length > 0) {
        return found_in_db[0];
      }
      var new_object = {
        a_property: 'some_default_value',
        start: date
      };
      console.log(new_object);
      return new_object;

    });
```

But currently I get this:
[image]

Comment: Can you give better explanations what you need?

Comment: I need to create calendar view with fullcalendar.io. For some dates I have price in database and I get it but for some dates I need to put usuall rates so that objects I need to create with javascript. Problem is now becouse I dont know how to make json for that. SO for every dates I need to have a price but for some dates I get data from database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this:

```
new Date(db_data.start.replace(" ", "T")).getTime() === date.getTime()
```

can ever be `true`.  The dates in db_data have a time set in them `"2016-03-15 15:18:46"`, but the dates you create in `array_of_all_dates` do not `Date('2016-02-02')`.

Your second date comparison seems to work, but I am unclear what it is you hope to be the result of the:

```
 array_of_all_dates.map( ... );
```

In some case you return an element from db_data which looks like this:

```
{ "id": 5", "user_id": 1, "article_id": 5, "title": "", "start": "2016-03-25 15:18:46" }
```

and if there was no "match" you return an object that looks like this:

```
{ a_property: 'some_default_value', start: date }
```

Note that all the original elements of `array_of_all_dates` are replaced by this operation.

What is it that you want to end up in `array_of_all_dates` so you can pass it to `drawCalendar`?

Comment: And yes that was a serioud problem becouse now I post in database: 2016-03-15 00:00:00 and works fine... Also is there any other better solution to solve this problem? What you can suggest to me ?

Comment: Well, then it seems your code (with the 2nd comparison) is doing what you want.